# Share via facebook using sharekit gives error auth failed:Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=6

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, sharekit

I am trying to implement sharing a link via facebook in my app using sharekit. But when I click on the share button it is giving me an error as

> SHKiOSSharer.m:(153)> auth failed:Error Domain=com.apple.accounts
>   Code=6 "(null)" 2017-12-07 18:59:25.705666+0530 Wishfie[3762:1552285]
>   <-[SHKiOSSharer presentNoAvailableAccountAlert] SHKiOSSharer.m:(176)>
>   User revoked access in settings.app, or in service itself. 2017-12-07
>   18:59:25.734617+0530 Wishfie[3762:1552285] <-[SHKSharer dealloc]
>   SHKSharer.m:(51)> !!! Facebook sharer deallocated!!!

My share function looks loke this

```
-(IBAction)shareButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender{

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"];
SHKItem *item = [SHKItem URL:url title:@"Some test title" contentType:SHKURLContentTypeWebpage];

[SHK setRootViewController:self];

// Display the action sheet
if (NSClassFromString(@"UIAlertController")) {

    //iOS 8+
    SHKAlertController *alertController = [SHKAlertController actionSheetForItem:item];
    [alertController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [alertController popoverPresentationController];
    popPresenter.barButtonItem = self.toolbarItems[1];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

} else {

    //deprecated
    SHKActionSheet *actionSheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];
    [actionSheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
}
```

What this error is and how to resolve it?

Comment: There are multiple other choices for sharing from iOS to Facebook - UIActivityViewController or Facebook's own SDK. Why do you want to use ShareKit? Or in other words, do you think something like ShareKit still has a value nowadays?

Comment: Might be funny that it is just me (ShareKit used-to-be maintainer) asking this. But I have few days I can devote to ShareKit (after a LONG time), and I am considering if it still worth the effort.

Comment: Yeah ... I finally gave up on sharekit and used UIActivityViewController.

Comment: Sorry for letting ShareKit without being updated. Anyway, if ShareKit worked well, what would be a reason to choose it instead of UIActivityViewController? If there is any such reason...